Why is react-select ui not updating although onchanage function is working?
I have a set of input that can be added incrementally. first, i cant set the value type to be "string" options shoots an error:

Type '{ value: string; options: { value: string; label: string; }[]; }' is not assignable to type 'DetailedHTMLProps<SelectHTMLAttributes, HTMLSelectElement>'.
Property 'options' does not exist on type 'DetailedHTMLProps<SelectHTMLAttributes, HTMLSelectElement>'.(2322)
so i have to set to any instead.


The Ui of my select input is not updating. despite logging the value and the onchange and both are working

  value: string
  label: string
}

const selectAssetsOptions: AssetOption[] = [
  { value: '12kg', label: '12kg' },
  { value: '25kg', label: '25kg' },
  { value: '50kg', label: '50kg' },
]
const [completeAssets, setCompleteAssets] = useState<
      { gasType: any; gasBotType: string }[]
  >([{ gasType: '', gasBotType: 'B2B GasBot' }])

const handleCompleteAssetChange = (index: number, value: string) => {
      console.log('complete Asset Change:', index, value)
      setCompleteAssets((prevAssets) => {
          const updatedAssets = [...prevAssets]
          updatedAssets[index] = { ...updatedAssets[index], gasType: value }
          return updatedAssets
      })
      console.log('Updated completeAssets:', completeAssets)
  }

  useEffect(() => {
      console.log('After Change - completeAssets:', completeAssets)
  }, [completeAssets])

{displayCompleteAssets && (
                      <>
                          {completeAssets.map((asset, index) => (
                              <div key={index} className="space-y-6">
                                  <div className="flex gap-3 items-center">
                                      <p className="font-semibold">
                                          Complete asset {index + 1}
                                      </p>
                                      {index > 0 && (
                                          <button
                                              type="reset"
                                              className="bg-[#ff0000] text-[#fff] rounded-full p-1 text-sm font-semibold"
                                              onClick={
                                                  handleRemoveCompleteAsset
                                              }
                                          >
                                              <IoMdClose />
                                          </button>
                                      )}
                                  </div>
                                  <div className="space-y-4">
                                      <Select
                                          value={
                                              completeAssets[index].gasType
                                          }
                                          options={selectAssetsOptions}
                                          defaultOptions={true}
                                          getOptionValue={completeAssets[index].gasType}
                                          placeholder="Cylinder Size"
                                          onChange={(selectedOption) => {
                                              console.log(
                                                  'Before Change - completeAssets:',
                                                  completeAssets
                                              )
                                              console.log(
                                                  'Value prop received by complete Asset Select:',
                                                  selectedOption.value
                                              )
                                              handleCompleteAssetChange(
                                                  index,
                                                  selectedOption.value
                                              )
                                              console.log(
                                                  'After Change - completeAssets:',
                                                  completeAssets
                                              )
                                          }}
                                      />

                                      <Input
                                          readOnly
                                          value={'B2B GasBot'}
                                          className="border-none bg-[#e8e8e8]"
                                          defaultValue={'B2B GasBot'}
                                      />
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          ))}
                          <div className="text-right">
                              <Button
                                  variant="solid"
                                  className="mt-auto align-baseline bg-[#194DA3] rounded-md"
                                  onClick={handleAddCompleteAsset}
                              >
                                  Add
                              </Button>
                          </div>
                      </>
                  )};`

apologies for the long code

